# Primefaces datatable don´t select with click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with a multiple selection option.

```
        <p:dataTable id="RecipientTable" var="Recipient"
        value="#{mainPageBean.recipients}"
        selection="#{mainPageBean.selectedRecipients}"
        rowKey="#{Recipient.recipientID}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
            listener="#{mainPageBean.recipientSelect}" update=":form:DebitorTable" />
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{mainPageBean.switchOtherTable}"
            update=":form:DebitorTable" />
        <f:facet name="header">Liste aller Recipients</f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="RecipientID" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Recipient.recipientID}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Value1" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Recipient.value1}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Value2" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Recipient.value2}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Ein Debitor hat Inkassoflag" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Recipient.debitorIncasso}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

My Problem is, that I only want to select a value when you click in the checkbox. When you click at the row, only the ajax event should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I dont use the . I use

```
       <p:column>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Recipient.selected}">
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{mainPageBean.selectRecipient}"
                    update=":form:confirmDialog" />
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="RecipientTable,:form:confirmDialog"
                        listener="#{mainPageBean.selectAllRecipients}" />
                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>
```

This simple create an own checkbox. Now I can set the selectionmode of the table to single and bind an ajax event to it.